# Asserting execution order in python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a function that creates a temporary directory, switches to that temporary directory, performs some work, and then switches back to the original directory. I am trying to write a unit test that tests this. I don't have a problem verifying that the current directory was changed to the temp dir and changed back again, but I'm having a problem verifying that the important stuff took place in between those calls.

My original idea was to abstract the function into three sub functions so that I could test the call order. I can replace each of the three sub functions with mocks to verify that they are called -- however, I am still presented with the issue of verifying the order. On a mock I can use assert_has_calls, but upon what object do I call that function?

Here is the class I'm trying to test:

```
import shutil
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile
import pkg_resources


class Converter:
    def __init__(self, encoded_file_path):
        self.encoded_file_path = encoded_file_path
        self.unencoded_file_path = None
        self.original_path = None
        self.temp_dir = None

    def change_to_temp_dir(self):
        self.original_path = os.getcwd()
        self.temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        os.chdir(self.temp_dir)

    def change_to_original_dir(self):
        os.chdir(self.original_path)
        shutil.rmtree(self.temp_dir)

    def do_stuff(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        self.change_to_temp_dir()
        self.do_stuff()
        self.change_to_original_dir()
```

This is as far as I got writing the test case:

```
def test_converter(self, pkg_resources, tempfile, subprocess, os, shutil):
    encoded_file_path = Mock()

    converter = Converter(encoded_file_path)
    converter.change_to_temp_dir = Mock()
    converter.do_stuff= Mock()
    converter.change_to_original_dir = Mock()

    assert converter.encoded_file_path == encoded_file_path
    assert converter.unencoded_file_path is None

    converter.run()
```

Now that I have each function mocked, I can verify THAT they were called, but not in what ORDER. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround would to be to create a separate mock object, attach methods to it and use [`assert_has_calls()`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.assert_has_calls) to check the call order:

```
converter = Converter(encoded_file_path)
converter.change_to_temp_dir = Mock()
converter.do_stuff = Mock()
converter.change_to_original_dir = Mock()

m = Mock()
m.configure_mock(first=converter.change_to_temp_dir,
                 second=converter.do_stuff,
                 third=converter.change_to_original_dir)

converter.run()
m.assert_has_calls([call.first(), call.second(), call.third()])
```

Comment: That doesn't work, the methods are still bound to Converter and don't have any effect on mock_stub. However it does give me an idea. What if you were to reverse the assignment? Instead of adding the converter functions to mock_stub, what if you replaced the converter functions with mock_stub functions?

Comment: @SeanPrice check that you instantiate the `m` mock after putting mocks on `converter` methods.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did. Your answer works well, thank you!